# How do I perfom Noob Saibot's finishing move in Mortal Kombat Trilogy?

Tags: mortal-kombat-trilogy

I have the Mortal Kombat Trilogy for both PS1 and PC and I have problems doing the finishing moves. According to http://www.mortalkombatonline.com/content/games/umk3/noobsaibot/, Noob Saibot's second fatality is:

```
(Close) Hold Block, Down, Down, Up, Run
```

So I hold down 5 (block) and press (not hold) down, down, up and 2 (run). He only weirdly crouches/holds block and nothing happens. Is there a trick to do it or something? Because from what I've seen in videos, the character doesn't move at all while performing the special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when you see moves like that, the last button should be pressed at the same time as the last direction button.  So it really should be more like:

```
Hold Block, Down, Down, Up + Run
```

Try it again.  Also note that you should be tapping the directions so you really shouldn't be holding them down for too long.

Answer (score 0):

Hoooray ...I did it

look .. be close to your opponent.. and you must release the block button before hitting ( Up+Run )

hold (block) then , down , down , then release the (block) , then (Up+Run)